# Link the question-ban meta FAQ on the question-ban help page

Tags: feature-request, post-ban, help-center

After a discussion with a question-banned user I realized that [the comprehensive question-ban meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) doesn't seem to be linked from the [question-ban help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). The user told me that they are only pointed to the help page, so the existence of the FAQ was news to them.

Could we add a link to the FAQ? Or is there a good reason why it isn't linked already? I can see that the FAQ is locked, but the reason seems to be that it's only to prevent off-topic comments from piling up (presumably from question-banned users). As I see it the FAQ is still relevant, locked or not.

Comment: I would even argue we should link from the message to both the Help and the FAQ ...

Comment: I suspect this help article is SE network-wide. I don't recall if all help pages could be branched to have site local versions

Comment: While we're at it, we could do this for all the help pages, since [there's an FAQ for most of the stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow), if not all. (It might already be linked for some topics)

Comment: @rene They probably could, but it would take dev work because they aren't at the moment.